# In TypeScript how do I figure out what needs passing in to a function without googling?

Tags: typescript

I'm a C# coder building something in Deno for fun, to learn. I've read all the manuals I can find but I'm still having trouble helping myself.

I want to use the `TextDecoder` to convert a `number[]` (I assume a byte array) into a string.

The `textDecoder.decode()` method takes a `BufferSource` which is an alias for a union of `ArrayBufferView | ArrayBuffer`. I have determined this by hitting **F12** and VSCode helpfully opens the source.

Ignoring, `ArrayBufferView` which is a rabbit hole of a question unto itself, I'm looking at `ArrayBuffer` which seems to be an interface in ES2015.

The MDN docs for `.decode()` have `buffer` as a an `ArrayBuffer`, a `TypedArray` or a `DataView` which is not apparent from hitting **F12** and wandering around the forest.

I feel like I'm doing this all wrong.

TypeScript is a structural type system, but the type aliases seem to obscure the structure of the object I am supposed to pass in.

For example, I had to look at the source code for `.decode()` and then drill down into that `BufferSource` to see what it really was.

**Question**: Should the compiler/autocomplete in VSCode help to show me what I can legally pass in, like showing me what's behind the alias?

I don't know what implements `ArrayBuffer` in order to make one. C# is more class oriented and things are usually named to reflect their heritage, like `SomethingArrayBuffer`.

In C# I would type `ArrayBuffer` and most of the time I'd see a bunch of suggestions for types containing that name and I'd then experiment with constructing one. That strategy doesn't seem to apply here.

I feel a bit stupid for not being able to figure it out alone, and googling everything. JS/TS is a different beast to C#, perhaps this is normal.

**Question**: Is there a way I could work out what to pass into `.decode()` without looking at MDN?

Perhaps I think C# is intuitive but it's an illusion of my experience.

Comment: `ArrayBufferView` is the interface that `TypedArray` and `DataView` extend. It's essentially the set of shared (common) properties of the things you *should* pass in. TypeScript doesn't care what you pass as long as it satisfies this interface.  And, the type system is not a substitute for documentation. They're two very different things. I think it's great that you have to reference the documentation.

Comment: Usually, when you start filling in arguments, the aliases decompose into their constituents. Same thing when you pass in the wrong argument, the error is more detailed. However, when something is an `interface` the name is opaque and you also get useless errors such as  `'foo' does not extend 'TextDecoderOptions'`. Your only options are to navigate through the forest as you say, or use a utility type like `type Inspect<T> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K]}` which will at least turn the interface into an object type of which you can see the properties. A recursive `InspectDeep` type can also be written.

Comment: Thanks. These comments are reassuring. I get the feeling I'll be answering my own question here in a year's time!